# How to render multiple columns with Markdown in GitHub README?

Tags: css, github, markdown

To render items in three columns, I attempted to add the following CSS3 directives to my project's `README.md` file, but the styling was stripped out:

```
<div style="-webkit-column-count: 3; -moz-column-count: 3; column-count: 3; -webkit-column-rule: 1px dotted #e0e0e0; -moz-column-rule: 1px dotted #e0e0e0; column-rule: 1px dotted #e0e0e0;">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <!-- first column's content -->
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <!-- second column's content -->
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <!-- third column's content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

This styling works correctly outside of GitHub's processing of Markdown. How can I put data into multiple columns in a Markdown document? Note that I am not concerned about support for IE browsers and don't care if IE renders a single column (my software project does not work on Windows clients, anyway).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GitHub-Flavored Markdown [only permits certain allow-listed tags and attributes in inline HTML](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/#html):

> ### HTML
>
> You can use a subset of HTML within your READMEs, issues, and pull requests.
>
> A full list of our supported tags and attributes can be found in [the README for github/markup](https://github.com/github/markup/tree/master#html-sanitization).

Regarding `<div>` tags, that README says that only the `itemscope` and `itemtype` attributes are allow-listed, in addition to the general attribute allowlist:

> `abbr`, `accept`, `accept-charset`, `accesskey`, `action`, `align`, `alt`, `axis`, `border`, `cellpadding`, `cellspacing`, `char`, `charoff`, `charset`, `checked`, `cite`, `clear`, `cols`, `colspan`, `color`, `compact`, `coords`, `datetime`, `dir`, `disabled`, `enctype`, `for`, `frame`, `headers`, `height`, `hreflang`, `hspace`, `ismap`, `label`, `lang`, `longdesc`, `maxlength`, `media`, `method`, `multiple`, `name`, `nohref`, `noshade`, `nowrap`, `prompt`, `readonly`, `rel`, `rev`, `rows`, `rowspan`, `rules`, `scope`, `selected`, `shape`, `size`, `span`, `start`, `summary`, `tabindex`, `target`, `title`, `type`, `usemap`, `valign`, `value`, `vspace`, `width`, `itemprop`

No tags support the `style` attribute.

Unless you can hack something together with the tags and attributes listed in that README I think you'll find that you're out of luck.

An alternative would be to put together a [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) site, which seems to be much more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind the borders, you can use tables https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/organizing-information-with-tables