# Markdown: 2 columns layout

Tags: markdown

Is possible to create a 2 columns layout using Markdown? I need something like this: text on the left and picture on the right

[image]

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30520338/866026) is related.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [syntax description](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html), you can place arbitrary HTML in Markdown, so yes, you can do it.

Comment: I agree, but [not with your "albeit"](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html). Remove it, and you get my +1.

Comment: and how come if i do something like `<table>
    <tr>
        <td># Massgeschneiderte<br>Lösungen für Firmen<br>und Privatpersonen</td>
        <td>![](illu.png)</td>
    </tr>
</table>`does not works?

Comment: Do you see the picture otherwise, when not surrounded by a table?

Comment: In general, Markdown does not work in the middle of HTML tags. Inside your `<table>` (or whatever other tag) you're stuck using plain HTML.