# How to disply two markdown code blocks side by side

Tags: markdown

I would like to display two blocks of a source codes side by side -before refactoring and after. Is it possible to create two code blocks side by side? If not then what is the alternative solution?

Comment: what's your output format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two columns code in Markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30514408/two-columns-code-in-markdown)

Comment: Ideally my output format would be html

Answer (score 18):

There is no way to create multi-line code blocks in a single table cell using bare Markdown syntax - but you can use verbatim HTML to accomplish this. Here is an example two-column table with side-by-side code (note that this HTML goes side-by-side with the rest of your Markdown):

````
# Document Title

The usual [Markdown Cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet)
does not cover some of the more advanced Markdown tricks, but here
is one. You can combine verbatim HTML with your Markdown. 
This is particularly useful for tables.
Notice that with **empty separating lines** we can use Markdown inside HTML:

<table>
<tr>
<th>Json 1</th>
<th>Markdown</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<pre>
{
  "id": 1,
  "username": "joe",
  "email": "joe@example.com",
  "order_id": "3544fc0"
}
</pre>
</td>
<td>

```json
{
  "id": 5,
  "username": "mary",
  "email": "mary@example.com",
  "order_id": "f7177da"
}
```

</td>
</tr>
</table>
````

which is rendered as:

[image: two-column table in markdown]

Comment: But then the code will not get automatic *syntax highlighting*.. bummer

Answer (score 9):

A modified version of the other answer does work to get side-by-side syntax highlighting on Github:

````
# Document Title

The usual [Markdown Cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet)
does not cover some of the more advanced Markdown tricks, but here
is one. You can combine verbatim HTML with your Markdown. 
This is particularly useful for tables.
Notice that with **empty separating lines** we can use Markdown inside HTML:

<table>
<tr>
<th>Json 1</th>
<th>Markdown</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
  
```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "username": "joe",
  "email": "joe@example.com",
  "order_id": "3544fc0"
}
```
  
</td>
<td>

```json
{
  "id": 5,
  "username": "mary",
  "email": "mary@example.com",
  "order_id": "f7177da"
}
```

</td>
</tr>
</table>
````

Demo: https://gist.github.com/nottheswimmer/7837eec10fac0d1197fc5a8bfc0b96f3