# Display code in two columns in restructured text

Tags: restructuredtext, code-documentation

Using restructured text, how can I display two code blocks side by side, so that they can be compared line by line?

Here is an example of what I mean from this similar question for Markdown: [How to disply two markdown code blocks side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35381425)

[image: Code in two columns]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found that the following works:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|                         |                         |
|.. code-block::          |.. code-block::          |
|                         |                         |
|   # Code example 1      |   # Code example 2      |
|                         |                         |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

This creates a table with two columns, and puts a code block in each of them. If the two blocks have the same number of lines, they will be aligned to each other. The output looks like this:

[image]

If one wants to include an external script, it can be done like this:

```
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|                                |                                |
|.. literalinclude:: script_1.py |.. literalinclude:: script_2.py |
|                                |                                |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```