# Moving author title and date to one column of a two-column page with markdown and pandoc for a PDF output

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

I am trying to produce a landscape-orientated page that is two-column. I want the author, title, and date to appear in the left-side column.  I set up the two columns following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40982836/latex-multicolumn-block-in-pandoc-markdown).

Currently, the author, title, and date are centered at the top of the page, and the rest of the page content follows below as two columns.

Here is the YAML header I am using:

---

```
title: Test
author: Name
date: \today
papersize: letter
fontsize: 11pt
documentclass: article
classoption: 
  - landscape
geometry: "left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm"
Header-includes:
    - \setlength\parindent{0pt}
    - \usepackage{multicol}
    - \newcommand{\hideFromPandoc}[1]{#1}
    - \hideFromPandoc{
        \let\Begin\begin
        \let\End\end
      }
```

---

is there anyway to shift things so that the intro material appears *in* (or maybe just above)  the left-side, such that the right-side column can use the entire page length?

Comment: I'm not a LaTeX pro, maybe take a look at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multiple_columns

Comment: I think the best way forward would be to use a [custom template](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates) and to ask on [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com) for help. Or ask there for a LaTeX-only solution, and then come back here for further help to use it with pandoc.

Comment: That seems right. Thanks for the suggestions!