# Failure to display 3 sections side-by-side

Tags: github-flavored-markdown

I have the following snippet of HTML in my `README.MD` file on GitHub:

```html
<footer>
<p style="float:left; width: 20%;">
Copyright © Jonathan Gossage, 2018
</p>
<p style="float:left; width: 60%; text-align:center;">
<a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/"><img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0" src="https://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-sa/4.0/88x31.png" /></a><br />This work is licensed under a <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/">Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International License</a>
</p>
<p style="float:left; width: 20%;">
Email addresses will be added when they are setup.
</p>
</footer>
```

This code is intended to display 3 sections side-by-side in an HTML footer. This code works in the preview window of my Markdown editor and it woks when placed in a standard HTML document and displayed by Google Chrome.

Unfortunately when GitHub renders the code to HTML the footer get displayed with the three sections displayed vertically. I tried this also using `<div>` instead of `<footer>` with the same result.

Can anyone suggest how I can display these sections side-by-side in a GitHub `README.MD` file?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub strips several tags and attributes, including inline styles, from HTML as part of its [processing of Markdown files](https://github.com/github/markup/blob/master/README.md#github-markup):

> The HTML is sanitized, aggressively removing things that could harm you and your kin—such as `script` tags, inline-styles, and `class` or `id` attributes. See the [sanitization filter](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/master/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb) for the full whitelist.

As far as I know there is no way to render content in columns in `README.md` files other than to use tables.

See also [How to render multiple columns with Markdown in GitHub README?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28201503/354577)