# Is there something like CSS columns in Markdown?

Tags: markdown

Sorry for the stupid question, something like the following (color list in vuetify) is too long and putting it in a table is too expensive, is there something like CSS-columns in markdown?

I want to present it in a compact form and usefully use the screen width.

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth, I think "the list is too long" is very arbitrary, and the solution of breaking it into columns is not a universally agreed-upon solution. I've seen many wikipedia pages where someone decided  to hard-code a long list into columns, and often times it looks like shit. It makes adding new entries to the list harder. It looks terrible on mobile devices. It might be a better solution to decide if the list can be broken up into logical sub-groups that make reading it (and understanding it) easier. Or just accepting that long lists are long.

Comment: dear @Anthony css columns are responsive, i.e. they look great on mobile devices; in fact e.g. as a long list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there something like css-columns in markdown?

No. Presenting content in multiple columns is a presentation concern, but [Markdown is all about content](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html):

> Markdown is not a replacement for HTML, or even close to it. Its syntax is very small, corresponding only to a very small subset of HTML tags. The idea is *not* to create a syntax that makes it easier to insert HTML tags. In my opinion, HTML tags are already easy to insert. The idea for Markdown is to make it easy to read, write, and edit prose. HTML is a *publishing* format; Markdown is a *writing* format. Thus, Markdown’s formatting syntax only addresses issues that can be conveyed in plain text.

You've tagged several Markdown processors in your question. Some of them may support columnar output, but others don't ([GitHub Flavored Markdown certainly doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28202804/354577), for example).

You'll have to specify the processor you're using if you want to talk about columns.