# Column of pictures in github markdown

Tags: html, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I created github markdown list of [awesome automotive](https://github.com/Marcin214/awesome-automotive) resources and I would like to improve it with some additional graphics.

My idea is that I want in parallel to the elements of the list, place different types of pictures in the column with specific size. Unfortunately, I do not know if it is possible to do it from separate pictures and without html tables. Do you know any example of such README or idea how to do it.

For example currently I could put only one picture which will be parallel to the next records:

```
## Autosar

<img align="right" width="200" src="media/autosar.png">

- [AUTOSAR](https://www.autosar.org/) - (**AUT**omotive **O**pen **S**ystem **AR**chitecture) is a worldwide development partnership of vehicle manufacturers, suppliers, service providers and companies from the automotive electronics, semiconductor and software industry.
```

If I want to add another picture under the one I have already added, I have to put it after few next record list, and I just want to avoid it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render multiple columns with Markdown in GitHub README?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28201503/how-to-render-multiple-columns-with-markdown-in-github-readme)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem. I expanded the description of question by with my current attempts.

Comment: Well the answer to that other question boils down to "you can't". It's not a way of _doing_ what you want, because there _is no_ way to do what you want.